# Is there a limit to the number of trials on a criminal charge permitted due to hung juries?

Tags: united-states, jury, trial, prosecutorial-discretion

In a jury trial for a criminal charge, [SCOTUS recently ruled that a guilty verdict must be unanimous](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/590/18-5924/).

In ([almost](https://verdict.justia.com/2020/07/01/should-acquittals-require-unanimity)) every state a verdict to *acquit* a criminal defendant must also be unanimous.

If a jury cannot reach a unanimous verdict (a.k.a. a [hung jury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hung_jury#United_States)) then the judge must declare a mistrial and the prosecutor can demand a new trial of the same defendant on the same charge.

Are there any legal constraints on the number of times that a defendant can be retried following mistrials due to hung juries?  Or is the only practical constraint the willingness of the prosecutor to expend government resources (and perhaps political capital) pursuing a conviction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any legal constraints on the number of times that a
> defendant can be retried following mistrials due to hung juries?

No. A fairly recent case in Louisiana, for example, involved someone who had been tried perhaps half a dozen times resulting in a mix of hung juries and reversals of convictions on appeal.

> Or is the only practical constraint the willingness of the prosecutor
> to expend government resources (and perhaps political capital)
> pursuing a conviction?

Yes. This is the only practical limitation.